# too much data xcb_xlib_too_much_data_requested

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, porting

A colleague and I are trying to port a C# program from Windows to Linux Mint 16.04 (32-bit) and are getting the error that an "xcb_xlib_too_much_data_requested" assertion failed, specifically:

```
[xcb] Too much data requested from _XRead
[xcb] This is most likely caused by a broken X extension library
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
cli: ../../src/xcb_io.c:736: _XRead: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_too_much_data_requested' failed.
```

Can anyone explain what this is about, where it comes from and how to fix it?

I have tried adding mono-reference-assemblies as suggested at the end of
https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp/issues/159, but that didn't fix the problem.

Thanks for thinking about this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but with Ubuntu. But when I run it with sudo, it works. So my guess is a configuration issue, but damned if I know which one.

Answer (score 1):

Since "xcb_xlib_too_much_data_requested" refers to xcb, I downloaded the latest version with the shell command

sudo apt-get install xcb

Fixed the problem :-)

Comment: I have the same problem, but installing xcb did not help.
Any other ideas how to solve this problem?